# Is Kurapika the only person who has 2 types of Nen?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

So according to the 2011 anime, persons can use different types of Nen to different levels of effectivity. But Kurapika is type Conjuration when he's normal, and type specialization when he's mad and his eyes turn into scarlet. Is he the only one who has this? Is Kurapika the only person who has 2 types of Nen?

Comment: He is the only survivor of the Kurta Clan so, yes, he is the only one.

Comment: Maybe in the Dark Continent have some creature who also can use 2 types of Nen. *Just sayin

Comment: @kit Possible but we won't know for sure unless it comes back from hiatus. I think it would be several chapters or maybe a few more volumes before they'll reach the Dark Continent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Kurapika is being taught about Nen, his teacher states that 1% of conjurers and manipulators also develop Specialist abilities. This means that Conjurer/Specialists and Manipulator/Specialists exist, but are extremely rare.

It is also worth noting that Emperor Time is a specialist ability that, while active, gives Kurapika 100% proficiency in all 6 types of Nen, at the cost of using 1 hour of his lifespan for each second it is active.

It is entirely reasonable that someone else may have a similar ability, such as a specialist who can change their Nen type each morning, giving them access to a Hatsu associated with that Nen type, or a Specialist who gave themself access to another Nen type with their Hatsu. Obviously, these would require appropriate limitations, but such is the core nature of the Nen system.